# QML pointer handlers and handling grab changes

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

In Qt 5.10 [Pointer Handlers](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qtquickhandlers-index.html) were introduced. I'm trying to use these instead of `MouseArea` in my application. In particular, I am using [DragHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-draghandler.html). I would like to determine when a drag has started and be notified of grab changes. Qt provides `DragHandler::grabChanged(GrabTransition transition, EventPoint point)` (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-draghandler.html#grabChanged-signal)) so in my code I am using this as:

```
DragHandler{
    id: dragHandler
    onGrabChanged: {
    // how to use transition ???
    }
}
```

However, the `GrabTransition` seems not to be implemented and the documentation doesn't give any clue on what values this enum can take.

Answer (score 2):

It's surprising that the documentation doesn't really explain this. From the source code, I was able to determine the code below. The comments come straight from the source code:

```
DragHandler {
    onGrabChanged: {
        switch (transition) {
        case EventPoint.GrabPassive:
        case EventPoint.GrabExclusive:
            break;
        case EventPoint.UngrabPassive:
        case EventPoint.UngrabExclusive:
            break;
        case EventPoint.CancelGrabPassive:
        case EventPoint.CancelGrabExclusive:
             // the grab was stolen by something else
            break;
        case EventPoint.OverrideGrabPassive:
            // Passive grab is still there, but we won't receive point updates right now.
            // No need to notify about this.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did also have a look at the source code and then tried your code, but I always get this: `ReferenceError: EventPoint is not defined`

Comment: That's strange. I don't get that error. What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: I was using Qt 6.2rc, but switching to 5.15 there are no errors. Although, it seems that the onGrabChanged handler is never called. I tested it with `onGrabChanged: console.debug("hello")` but qml doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 1):

For QT 6.2 GrabTransition enum located in PointerDevice

```
 enum GrabTransition {
    GrabPassive = 0x01,
    UngrabPassive = 0x02,
    CancelGrabPassive = 0x03,
    OverrideGrabPassive = 0x04,
    GrabExclusive = 0x10,
    UngrabExclusive = 0x20,
    CancelGrabExclusive = 0x30,
};
```

So it would be e.g `PointerDevice.GrabPassive`